# help to prove $||u||_{W^{2,2}(\Omega) }\le C ||\Delta u ||_{L^2(\Omega )} $

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Can some one give a reference or hint for proving

> $$||u||_{W^{2,2}(\Omega)} \le C ||\Delta u ||_{L^2(\Omega )} $$

Comment: Any harmonic function violates that inequality.

Comment: @Jose27: you are clearly right, but I think here we are assuming $u_{|\partial\Omega}=0$ or something similar, so this is just the Poincaré-Wirtinger inequality.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246790/sobolov-space-w2-2-cap-w1-2-0-norm-equivalence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $u\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)\cap W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ and $\partial\Omega\in C^2$, then the inequality will be hold. Indeed, we have the PDE
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u=-\Delta u &x\in\Omega\\
u=0&x\in\partial \Omega
\end{cases}
has solution $u\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ and hence by outer regularity we have 
$$ \|u\|_{W^{2,2}(\Omega)}\leq C\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} $$
which is the desired result.