# $ W_{0}^{2}(\Omega)=\{ f\in W_{0}^{1}(\Omega):\Delta f\in L^{2}(\Omega)\}? $

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, laplacian

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open bounded domain. Let
$W^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$ be the usual Sobolev space 
$$
W^{2}\left(\Omega\right)=\left\{ f\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right):f,\partial_{i}f,\partial_{ij}^{2}f\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)\right\} .
$$
Let $W_{0}^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$ be the closure of $C_{0}^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$
w.r.t. $W^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$-norm in $W^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$.

> Question: is it true that
>   $$
> W_{0}^{2}\left(\Omega\right)=\left\{ f\in W_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right):\Delta f\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)\right\} ?
> $$
>   That is, the Laplacian controls $\partial_{ij}^{2}$ in $L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this space is not the same as $W_0^2$. Note that $W_0^2$ and $W_0^1 \cap W^2$ are different spaces. In $W_0^2$ we additionally the information that $\nabla f \in (H_0^1(\Omega))^n$, i.e. that the first derivatives vanish on the boundary of $\partial \Omega$ in some sense (with the trace operator, so we have $\text{Tr}(\nabla f) = \partial_\nu f=0$ where $\nu$ is some outer normal to the sufficiently smooth domain $\Omega$).

You lose this important property in your space. But, your proposed space is indeed the same as $W_0^1 \cap W^2$, which was proven for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246790/sobolov-space-w2-2-cap-w1-2-0-norm-equivalence?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: The last paragraph is only true if $\Omega$ is nice enough.