# confused in the choice of norms

Tags: normed-spaces

i want to prove that the followinf function is bijection:
$$A: H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)\cap H^{2}(\Omega) \to  L^{2}(\Omega)$$

$\Omega$ is $C^{1}$ bounded  domain of $R^{n}$
and the hint was to use lax milgram theorem

so i consider
\begin{array}{ll}
                             -\Delta u=f, & \hbox{$\ \in \Omega$,} \\
                            u=0\in \partial \Omega. & \hbox{}
                           \end{array}
and $f \in L^{2}(\Omega)$

first i used this theorem with V$=( H_{0}^{1}(\Omega),\lvert. \rvert_{H_{0}^{1}})$ since with  elliptic regularity i will have that u $\in H^{2}(\Omega)$ but im not sure that is the best answer and im thinking to use the lax milgram with W$=(H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)\cap H^{2}(\Omega),\lvert \Delta .\rvert_{2})$ because W is banach space (as you can see [Sobolov Space $W^{2,2}\cap W^{1,2}_0$ norm equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246790/sobolov-space-w2-2-cap-w1-2-0-norm-equivalence/246837#246837))
so what space i should consider V or W
thanks